# Html5: What attributes do I change with html, css and javascript, respectively?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm a backend programmer trying to learn HTML5.

I wonder how to know what attributes can be changed directly in html and what attributes have to be changed with Javascript. Or with CSS?

Is there a reference keeping track of this? Or do I miss something? Should it be obvious in some way?

(I started wondering when I wanted to change the start up volume in the audio element. I didn't want it to start at highest possible volume. But I couldn't find any volume attribute in HTML5, even though there is one in the DOM reference...)

Edit: Thank you for explaining the difference between attributes and properties. Now correct me if I'm wrong:

- In both the DOM reference and the HTML5 reference I can find all possible HTML5 elements.
- In the DOM reference I can find all possible properties of an element (editable with javascript)
- In the HTML5 reference I can find all possible attributes of an element (editable with html).
- The DOM properties include the HTML attributes of the element.

If the above is true, my real question is: Is there a DOM reference that highlights the HTML attributes so that I don't have to look in two different references? –  Dudute 18 hours ago

Comment: HTML is for attributes, CSS is for styles, and the DOM (JavaScript) is for properties.

Comment: What about muted, is it both attribute and property then?

Comment: could you be more precious - which attribute, post some code, what you want to achieve, etc.?

Comment: @Dudute see the edit on my answer considering the `muted` attribute. There's an explanation for that too. I do agree that it's a quite fine line between attribute and DOM property sometimes though.

Comment: Now correct me if I'm wrong. In a DOM reference I can find all the properties of an element, and the properties also include the attributes of the HTML element. If that is true, my real question is: Is there a DOM reference that highlights the HTML attributes to simplify life for beginners like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically like this:

If you are using a HTML attribute like `name=""` it has to do with the output the tag has on the page. For example the `name` or `title` attributes affect the way input elements submit in a form, or the tooltip for the element (resp.), which has to do with the output on the page.

In CSS you can only change styles. CSS is for layout, and the way things look on your page. For example `display:none;` hides the element. First the HTML is loaded and then the styles are applied, so first the way the element is generated is determined (via attributes etc.) and then the layout is applies

Finally, in the JavaScript DOM, you apply properties. For the audio element you're talking about, that means you set the volume for example. This is not directly related to the way the output is on your page, so it's not a HTML attribute, but it does have to do with the way the element works, which is why it's a DOM property.

`muted` is also an attribute on the audio element, since that would make the audio player render as silent instead of rendering it as audible. This can then later be changed via the audio controls, but initially there is a difference between a muted audio element or an audible one, which is why it's an attribute. I agree it's a fairly fine line between attribute and DOM property though.

PS: if you want to change the volume in the HTML without needing to do it in a seperate script tag, just add an event listener for the `load` event, for example via the `onload` attribute:

```
<audio onload="this.volume = 0.9"></audio>
```